# Resume Using LaTeX (res.cls style)

Tags: pdftex, resume

I tried to use the **res.cls** as the resume template, but I found that it is very hard to adjust the margin since this documentclass is very old.

So can anyone please tell me if there's any other documentclass produce the resume style like this:
[image]

It's like the titles (Education, Employment, etc.) are on the left sides, and the rest on the right sides...

I just tried to change the margin of res.cls, and it works with a lot of bugs

Comment: There are many CV-related packages, see https://ctan.org/search?phrase=cv (stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58678426). But I recommend not using LaTeX for a CV since a CV is very specific and the LaTeX packages for CVs typically do not have good documentation AFAIK. Personally, I use a web service for my CV.

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out an easier way to achieve the same result:

Use the package `\usepackage{paracol}`

Adjust the column ratio using command `\columnratio{0.125}`

Switch column using command `\switchcolumn`

The environment `\begin{paracol}{2} ... \end{paracol}` helps you create the resume you like.

Note: I found the `res.cls` class is **obsolete**, so customizing it in LaTeX2e is a little bit difficult.